# Highlighting data range whille retaining original data label axis

Tags: excel, highlight, scatter-plot

So I'm not sure whether this can be done or not, but I want to highlight certain scatter plot points on my graph whilst still retaining the original axis labels. This is a little snip of my data:-

```
(0.5,0.525] 272
(0.925,0.95]    116
(0.975,1]   446
(1,1.025]   2840
(1.975,2]   974
(2,2.025]   1400
```

I have a scatter plot of the first column as my x-axis and the second column as my y-axis. Currently I'm highlighting the points that I want (such as `(1,1.025]    2840`by adding it as a new legend entries series, but to get it to align horizontally with the original data I've had to number all the points from 1 onwards and add the horizontal axis labels that way, so that all the points that are highlighted mask the other points behind it that contain the horizontal data labels. Is there a way of overcoming this without formatting the data for the x-axis numerically? Or a way of incorporating the data labels separately?

[image]

Just to illustrate the problem, I've attached an image at the end of this post. The columns mzRange and Frequency on the left handside were used to plot the graphs, whilst the columns on the right handside of the graph were used to highlight the points on the bottom graph. However, as the x-axis is labelled with the bin ranges from the column on the left, it goes up in a numerical fashion as seen with the numbers on the left most column, meaning I have to use the position number of the bins to then place the highlighted points (as seen with the column on the right handside of the graph that goes 18,34,36 etc) which in turn hides the information of the m/z bin range. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? It's hard to understand what you want. What do you mean with "adding it as a new legend entries series"? And I don't quite understand what you mean by numbering the points. Could you explain that in a bit more detail? Best would be a sample file. Think file sharing service.

Comment: Just uploaded an image to demonstrate the problem. Basically when I need a way of retaining the information of the mzRange of each highlighted point, but because the data is plotted not bins but sequentially (so if there's 200 bins then the range is from 0-200) I can't keep the information on the graph as a data label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in the mzRange is not numeric. If it is used as the data source for the X axis, it will result in the data points being numbered ascending on the X axis.

The only way to plot over a data point is to use the exact X and Y values as the original data point. You could mark the highlights in a column next to the original mzRange column and then plot the whole column.

See this screenshot:

[image]

Note how the X axis has nothing in common with the values of column B, although that was used as the data source for the X axis. The red dot highlights are placed in the rows that determine the position on the X axis. This way, the label that appears when hovering over the data point remains intact.